# BizTalk message box full of BTXTimerMessage messages

Tags: biztalk, edi, biztalk-2013r2

We are using BizTalk (2013 R2 CU 6) EDI functionality to batch EDI files. This uses the Microsoft.BizTalk.Edi.BatchingOrchestration.BatchingService Orchestration which is always running in a waiting state (for lack of a better term), dehydrated most of the time. While running the orchestration builds up instances of the BTXTimerMessages in the Queued (awaiting processing) state. These messages are never removed or processed, that I can tell. This eventually causes us to pass the 50k message threshold and start throttling.

As far as I can tell there is no way to setup a reoccurring schedule for the batcher, it must always run or be manually started. If we leave the batcher off there we get routing errors.

Currently the only way we have to eliminate these messages is to terminate the EDI batcher for each party, then restart it.

Is there a better way to purge these messages from the system, or stop them from being generated all together?